# JSP page executes Java code several times

Tags: jsp

Even a simple `System.out.println()` is executed several times. And with a loop it's the same. What could be the reasons? I don't know what additional info could help you, so please tell me if you need to know something else.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="db.DBManager, data.Klausur, data.Benutzer, common.Tuple, common.Berechtigung, java.util.ArrayList, java.util.HashMap, java.util.Date, java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<%@ include file="fragments/head-section.jspf"%>
<title>CHEAT - Klausur w&auml;hlen</title>
</head>

<%
int benutzerID = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("benutzerID").toString());
%>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
if (<%=benutzerID%><=0) {
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function() {
        window.location.href = "index.jsp";
    });
}
</script>
<%
session.setAttribute("benutzerID",benutzerID);
Object kID = session.getAttribute("klausurID");
int alterKlausurID = 0;
if(kID != null) {
    alterKlausurID = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("klausurID").toString());
    session.setAttribute("klausurID", alterKlausurID);
    }
%>

<body>

<jsp:useBean id="dbm" class="db.DBManager"></jsp:useBean>

<%
    // Änderungen an der Datenbank (eintragen, ändern, löschen) werden vorgenommen

    //alterMsg: Klausur erfolgreich eingetragen etc.
    String alterMsg = ""; 
    String alterName = request.getParameter("name");
    String alterDateString = request.getParameter("date");

    String participants = request.getParameter("teilnehmer");

    // Die User-Rechte werden abgefragt

    ArrayList<Benutzer> users = new ArrayList<Benutzer>(dbm.getAllUsers());
    System.out.println("Anzahl Benutzer: "+users.size());
    HashMap<Integer,Berechtigung> radios = new HashMap<Integer,Berechtigung>();
    for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
        Benutzer b = users.get(i);
        int id = b.getBenutzerID();

        Berechtigung userRight = Berechtigung.nix;

        try{
        userRight = Berechtigung.valueOf(request.getParameter(""+id));
        //System.out.println(">>DEBUG userRight: "+userRight.toString());
        }catch(Exception e){}

        switch (userRight)
        {
        case admin:
            radios.put(new Integer(id), Berechtigung.admin);
            //System.out.println("UserRecht von "+id+" geändert auf admin");
            break;
        case korrektur:
            radios.put(new Integer(id), Berechtigung.korrektur);
            //System.out.println("UserRecht von "+id+" geändert auf korrektur");
            break;
        case statistik:
            radios.put(new Integer(id), Berechtigung.statistik);
            //System.out.println("UserRecht von "+id+" geändert auf statistik");
            break;
        default: //nix
            radios.put(new Integer(id), Berechtigung.nix);
            //System.out.println("UserRecht von "+id+" geändert auf nix");
            break;

        }

        //System.out.println(">>DEBUG ID: "+id);
    }

    //Rechte eintragen
    //dbm.alterRights(alterKlausurID, radios);

    boolean isMsg = false;
    try {
        boolean delete = Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("deleteExam"));
        if (delete) {
            dbm.deleteExam(alterKlausurID);
            alterMsg = "Klausur erfolgreich gel&ouml;scht!";
            isMsg = true;
        } else if (alterKlausurID == -1) {
            dbm.createExam(alterName, alterDateString, benutzerID, radios, participants);
            alterMsg = "Klausur erfolgreich eingetragen!";
            isMsg = true;
        } else if (alterKlausurID > 0) {
            dbm.alterExam(alterKlausurID, alterName, benutzerID, alterDateString, radios, participants);
            alterMsg = "Klausur erfolgreich ge&auml;ndert!";
            isMsg = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }           
%>

<!-- HEADER -->
<%@ include file="fragments/header.jspf"%>

<!-- CONTENT -->
<div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
    <table id="selectExamHeading">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h1>Klausurauswahl</h1>
            </td>
            <td id="selectExamHeadingRight">
                <!-- "Neue Klausur"-Button --> <jsp:element name="a">
                <jsp:attribute name="class">createExamLink</jsp:attribute>
                <jsp:attribute name="href">administrateExam.jsp?klausurID=-1</jsp:attribute>
                <jsp:attribute name="data-role">button</jsp:attribute>
                <jsp:attribute name="data-ajax">false</jsp:attribute>
                <jsp:attribute name="data-icon">plus</jsp:attribute>
                <jsp:body>Klausur erstellen</jsp:body>
            </jsp:element>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <%
    if (isMsg) { %>
    <p class="msg"><div class="msgBg"></div><span class="msgInner"><%=alterMsg%></span></p>
    <% } %>

    <%
        /*
         * Es werden alle Klausuren geladen, die der aktuelle Benutzer korrigieren darf.
         * Für jede geladene Klausur wird ein Button erstellt
         * das Attribute "data-ajax" bei Links dient dazu, dass der Datepicker auf der nächsten Seite
         * sofort geladen wird (nicht erst nach Refresh der Seite) [Workaround]
         */

        String output = "";
        ArrayList<Tuple<Klausur,Benutzer>> list = new ArrayList<Tuple<Klausur,Benutzer>>(dbm.getExamsForUserID(benutzerID));

        if (list.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                Klausur k = list.get(i).getFirst();
                String name = k.getName();
                String kAnzeigeName;
                int l = name.length();
                if (l > 41) {
                    kAnzeigeName = name.substring(0,18) + "..." + name.substring(l-18, l);
                } else {
                    kAnzeigeName = name;
                }
                int klausurID = k.getKlausurID();
                Benutzer b = list.get(i).getSecond();
                String erstellerName = b.getName()+", "+b.getVorname();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
                String datum = sdf.format(k.getDate().getTime()).toString();
    %>

    <jsp:element name="div">
                <jsp:attribute name="class">selectExamDiv</jsp:attribute>
                <jsp:attribute name="data-role">controlgroup</jsp:attribute>
                <jsp:attribute name="data-type">horizontal</jsp:attribute>
                <jsp:body>
                <jsp:element name="a">
                    <jsp:attribute name="class">bigSelectExamLink</jsp:attribute>
                    <jsp:attribute name="href">correctExam.jsp?klausurID=<%=klausurID%></jsp:attribute>
                    <jsp:attribute name="data-role">button</jsp:attribute>
                    <jsp:attribute name="data-ajax">false</jsp:attribute>
                    <jsp:body><%=kAnzeigeName%></br>
                        <jsp:element name="span">
                            <jsp:attribute name="class">examSubtitleName</jsp:attribute>
                            <jsp:body><%=erstellerName%></jsp:body>
                        </jsp:element>
                        <jsp:element name="span">
                            <jsp:attribute name="class">examSubtitleDate</jsp:attribute>
                            <jsp:body><%=datum%></jsp:body>
                        </jsp:element>
                    </jsp:body>
                </jsp:element>
                <jsp:element name="a">
                    <jsp:attribute name="class">smallSelectExamLink</jsp:attribute>
                    <jsp:attribute name="href">administrateExam.jsp?klausurID=<%=klausurID%></jsp:attribute>
                    <jsp:attribute name="data-role">button</jsp:attribute>
                    <jsp:attribute name="data-ajax">false</jsp:attribute>
                    <jsp:attribute name="data-icon">wrench-costum-big</jsp:attribute>
                    <jsp:attribute name="data-iconpos">bottom</jsp:attribute>
                </jsp:element>
                <jsp:element name="a">
                    <jsp:attribute name="class">smallSelectExamLink</jsp:attribute>
                    <jsp:attribute name="href">statistics.jsp?klausurID=<%=klausurID%></jsp:attribute>
                    <jsp:attribute name="data-role">button</jsp:attribute>
                    <jsp:attribute name="data-ajax">false</jsp:attribute>
                    <jsp:attribute name="data-icon">stats-costum-big</jsp:attribute>
                    <jsp:attribute name="data-iconpos">bottom</jsp:attribute>
                    <jsp:body></jsp:body>
                </jsp:element>
                </jsp:body>
                </jsp:element>
    <%
        }
            // Falls der aktuelle Benutzer bei keiner Klausur als Korrektor eingetragen ist, erscheint nur "Neue Klausur"
        } else {
            output = "Sie sind bei keiner Klausur als Korrektor eingetragen!";
            out.println(output);
        }
    %>

    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <%@ include file="fragments/footer-small.jspf"%>
</div>

<!-- Die DB-Verbindung muss noch geschlossen werden -->
<%@ include file="fragments/closeConnection.jspf"%>
```

Comment: Check the access log to see how many times the JSP was requested. Then reduce the problem to the simplest single JSP that recreates the issue and post that JSP.

Comment: You seriously need to read [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1031945)

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should. Thank you!

Comment: But is this really causing the problem?